# How to connect Pyspark with Teradata?

Tags: apache-spark, jdbc, pyspark, teradata

I need to connect Pyspark with Teradata, and the code I'm using for this is:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

appName = "PySpark Teradata Example"
master = "local"

# Create Spark session
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName(appName) \
    .master(master) \
    .getOrCreate()

driver = 'com.teradata.jdbc.TeraDriver'

# Define the function to load data from Teradata


def load_data(driver, jdbc_url, sql, user, password):
    return spark.read \
        .format('jdbc') \
        .option('driver', driver) \
        .option('url', jdbc_url) \
        .option('dbtable', '({sql}) as src'.format(sql=sql)) \
        .option('user', user) \
        .option('password', password) \
        .load()

sql = "select * from AdventureWorksDW.DimAccount"
url = "192.168.xx.xxx"
user = "dbc"
password = "dbc"

df_td = load_data(driver,url,sql,user,password)
df_td.show(10)
```

I'm running the above script using the following Spark-submit command in cmd

```
spark-submit --jars terajdbc4.jar spark.py
```

And I get the error as:

> File
> "..\spark.py",
> line 32, in 
> df_td = load_data(driver,url,sql,user,password)
> File "..\spark.py",
> line 25, in load_data
> .load()
> File "C:\SPARK\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 164, in load
> File
> "C:\SPARK\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.9.2-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1309, in **call**
> File
> "C:\SPARK\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py",
> line 117, in deco pyspark.sql.utils.IllegalArgumentException:
> requirement failed: The driver could not open a JDBC connection. Check
> the URL: 192.168.xx.xxx

What could be the issue?

Comment: The url needs to be a JDBC URL not just an IP or hostname, e.g. `jdbc:teradata://192.168.xx.xxx`